# New To XMPPFrameWork

Tags: ios, iphone

iam Very new To XMPPFramework,i want to do Login and registration Page by using XmppFramework so can any one guide me how to do and provide me some tutorials or links if any one have, it will be helpfull to me thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following links

[Github](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)
And [Starting steps](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS)

Comment: ya i seen but i want any example of registration n login then i can understand the implementation also.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **XMPPFramework** I recommend you this basic tutorial [iOS chat](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup--mobile-6958)

And a theoretical guide http://xmpp.org to understand how XMPP works.

Comment: can u explani me thericaly what is xmpp n what it dos and how to do the chat with it and finally what is jabber

Comment: tell me the jabber  and xmpp does?